# jQuery select next occurrence of some element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I select some element with `.someClass` and I want to select next `<label>` element which occurs lower in the DOM tree.

Between those two elements can be anything else, e.g:

```
<input class="someClass" />
<p>asdfasdf</p>
<div></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>SOMETHING</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My script:

```
 $(".question").each(function (index, value) { 
     vargroupNumber = ++index;
     $(":radio", this)
     .attr("name", "group" + groupNumber)
     .each(function (index, value) {        
         $(this)
         .removeAttr('checked')
         .attr("id", "id" + groupNumber + index)
         .next('label') 
         .‌​attr("for", "id" + groupNumber + index); 
     }); 
 });
```

I want to select and set something to this `<label>`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i did many things :D It works for predefined layout but other than that it's complicated... Actually my case is bit more complex, this is how it works only if <label> is right next to a :radio button ->   $(".question").each(function(index,value) {
         var groupNumber = ++index;
         $(":radio", this).attr("name", "group" + groupNumber).each(function(index,value){
          $(this).removeAttr('checked').attr("id","id"+groupNumber+index).next('label').attr("for","id"+groupNumber+index);
         });
  });

Comment: post code sample of what you've tried so far and what isn't working.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes i just did

Comment: on what basis you want to select `<lable>`, does it share the same class name with other element(s) on DOM or what?

Comment: just because it appears under down the DOM tree from current one...on that basis

Comment: why don't you set a class to your label, like this: `<label class="resultLabel">SOMETHING</label>` - now you can set content to it like this: `$('.resultLabel').html('what-ever-you-want');`

Comment: in that case i would not bother anyone to help me :) not possible...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: Forget the DOM structure, just find the next element with this class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873027/jquery-forget-the-dom-structure-just-find-the-next-element-with-this-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873187/1995170) (and even ["pluginified"](http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/)).

Comment: I really don't understand how come that they didn't make this part f jquery already. This is bit abstract but can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by **Recursion** here is the code

```
var elem = $('.someClass');

findlabel(elem)

function findlabel(elem) {

if (elem.prop('tagName') == 'LABEL') {
    elem.text('yahoo');
    //do what you want to do
} else if (!elem.is(':empty')) {

    var notfound = 1;
    elem.find('*').each(function () {

        if ($(this).prop('tagName') == 'LABEL') {
            $(this).text('yahoo');
            //do what you want to do
            notfound = 0;
            return false;
        }

    });

    if (notfound == 1) {
        elem = elem.next();
        findlabel(elem);
    }

} else {
    elem = elem.next();
    findlabel(elem);
}
}
```

and here is the working example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/LLkdA/

i hope this is what you want

Answer (score -1):

Try

`$(".someClass").parent("body").find("label");`

Instead of the `body` use whatever the parent of `someClass` and `table` is.

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/YrNRc/)

Comment: That only works if <label> is just next to .someClass element.

Answer (score -1):

Your definately going to want to use Jquery's next function. I asked basically the same question and got my answer

[Getting Div ID on Header Click, Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229814/getting-div-id-on-header-click-accordion)

Comment: this is not the same question, please read carefully. This answer won't work for @mariotanenbaum.